# Responsive bootstrap carousel multiple columns in item

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I was wondering how to achieve responsive layout with `bootstrap carousel` with multiple columns in each item.

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/L4bA8/

On mobile I need all columns to slide, but there can be only one column per item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this isnt a thing doable with bootstrap only, you have to write some custom javascript. I am facing the same issue and i found this Bootply that may help you as it helped me:

http://www.bootply.com/132400

Comment: There is an issue with this version of jquery solution. If the item is less than 3 then it is duplicating the item. http://www.bootply.com/dMnK7SqFrr

Answer (score -2):

[Do you mean something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/L4bA8/3/)
add `col-xs-` for column size on mobile

Comment: No, I need to convert 3 columns in each of 4 slides (on col-sm and larger) to 1 column in each of 12 slides (on col-xs). Now I just create two different carousels and display them separately on different display sizes.