# Bootstrap Carousel display 1 column on breakpoint

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So I have a carousel that displays 4 grids, i'd like it to show just 1 grid (col-sm-12) on mobile devices, anyone know how I could achieve this with jquery or css?

Currently it's listing 4 grids just at col-sm-12, i want it to show 1 grid at col-sm-12:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Arrival Dec, 2013</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Arrival, November, 2013</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Arrival Feb, 2014, ON</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Arrival March 2014, ON</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked before: [Responsive bootstrap carousel multiple columns in item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075661/responsive-bootstrap-carousel-multiple-columns-in-item)

You can either use CSS/jQuery like show in this bootply: http://www.bootply.com/dMnK7SqFrr.
Or create two carousels and show them depending on display size.

I had a similar requirement recently, and after trying a first implementation based on above examples, I decided to go with [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). It's made for being responsive.